# componentDidUpdate creates infinite loop and not sure how to avoid it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, backend

Hi I am calling componentdidupdate in order to re-render my page with new ToDos like so

```
        this.state = {
            displayToDos: false,
            displayLanding: true,
            todo: {
                title: '',
                task: ''
            },
            todos: [],
            createdToDo: null,
            updateModal: false
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchItems()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
        if (prevState.todos !== this.state.todos) {
            this.fetchItems()
        }
    }

    fetchItems = async () => {
        try {
            const todos = await getItems()
            this.setState({ todos })
            console.log('set state of todos', this.state.todos)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }
```

my intended behavior for my app is that the component mounts fetches the items and sets them to state, and then whenever I make a post, update or delete call the state of todos changes and it fires off the fetch call to re render the todos on the page. However I am getting an infinite loop, how do I fix this?

Comment: since `todos` is an array and the reference to the array changes so `componentDidUpdate` always trigger `fetchItem`

Comment: `if (prevState.todos !== this.state.todos)` change this to individual item check using loop

Comment: hi thanks for the explanation but i am still confused sorry..., how would I go about implementing the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare arrays like this:
`let arraysEqual = JSON.stringify(todo) == JSON.stringify(todo1);` 
Or I will suggest you use this library [Loadsh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)
you can use the [`.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) method to check the arrays.